# Redirecting a domain using IIS

Tags: iis, redirect

I am currently having two domains www.xyz.com and www.pqr.com. If anybody enters xyz.com I need to bringout the website pqr.com

Both are on the same server.

Kindly suggest how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

- In internet services manager, right
  click on the file or folder you wish
  to redirect  then select "Properties"
- Select the radio titled    "a redirection to a URL".
- Enter the redirection page
- Check "The exact url entered above" and the "A permanent redirection for this resource"
- Click on 'Apply'

Comment: Also, if you are using IIS, and not Apache, you could serve names for multiple hosts from one web site.

Comment: on first step, add at the end of line, "then select "Properties..""

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true

> To redirect requests to another Web
>   site or directory
>
> 1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, right-click the Web site or
>      directory you want to redirect, and
>      click Properties.
> 2. Click the Home Directory, Virtual Directory, or Directory tab.
> 3. Under The content for this source should come from, click A redirection
>      to a URL.
> 4. In the Redirect to box, type the URL of the destination directory or
>      Web site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say that "you should always go to foo instead of bar," you want a 301 redirect (which you do with your front-end server). See http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633

A 302 (temporary) redirect should be used in cases where you can't serve a page, but expect it to come back later. Unfortunately, it's the redirect that you get from JSP forward.

A client-side (meta refresh or javascript) redirect should be avoided whenever possible.

[Apache docs for configuring a permanent (or temporary) redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

Comment: Ugh, need to be more explicit about using iis

Answer (score 0):

If you want pqr.com to appear in the user's browser's address bar, you'll have to send a 301/302 redirect response, either through a script or through your web server's configuration - how to do this depends on what software you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS7 and you have installed [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) then use this article for more information : [IIS URL Rewrite – Redirect multiple domain names to one](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/30/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one.aspx)