# IIS website query

Tags: iis

I have two websites on IIS but I need to pick up the pages from 2nd website directory on IIS when the user visits the 1st website. But I do not want to use redirection. I am giving the folder of 2nd website in settings of 1st website but it is showing the autentication dialog box when I try to visit the 1st website

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997501/redirecting-a-domain-using-iis

Comment: no, this is another issue that i am facing. Earlier was related to usage of redirection

Answer (score 1):

Instead of two IIS 'sites', try one site with two host-header identities?

http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a virtual directory on the 1st website referencing the home directory of the 2nd website?  That should work though the authentication makes me wonder what is triggering that, e.g. IIS security settings, ACL settings on the files and folders themselves, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

When I am I am giving the folder of 2nd website in settings of 1st website, I am actually giving the root folder and not path of any virutal directory.